# Is differentiating with respect to a function or multiple variables simulaneously legitmate, and if so, am I doing it correctly?

Tags: functions, derivatives

I am currently playing with differentiating functions with respect to other functions as well as differentiating multiple variables simultaneously. I am aware of the partial derivative and that one can differentiate with respect to two variables in succession (e.g. differentiating *xy* with respect to *x* and *y*), but I am wondering if it is legitimate to differentiate two variables simultaneously, as well as differentiate a function with respect to another function.

Example 1: $${d \over de^x}x^2$$
Let $$u = e^x, \space x = ln(u)$$
Then $${d \over de^x}x^2 = {d \over du}ln(u)^2 = {2ln(u) \over u} = {2x \over e^x}$$

Example 2: $${d \over dsin(x)}x^2$$
Let $$u = sin(x), \space x = arcsin(u)$$
Then $${d \over dsin(x)}x^2 = {d \over du}arcsin(u)^2 = {2arcsin(u) \over \sqrt{1 - u^2}} = {2x \over \sqrt{1 - sin(x)^2}}$$

Example 3: $${d \over d{1 \over x}}x^2$$
Let $$u = {1 \over x}, \space x = {1 \over u}$$
Then $${d \over d{1 \over x}}x^2 = {d \over du}{1 \over u^2} = {-2 \over u^3} = -2x^3$$

Example 4: $${d \over d(x+y)}x^2y^2$$
Let $$u = x + y, \space x = u - y, \space y = u - x$$
Then $${d \over d(x+y)}x^2y^2 = {d \over du}(u-y)^2(u-x)^2 = 2(u-x)(2-y)(2u-x-y) = 2xy(2x + 2y - x - y) = 2xy(x + y) = 2x^2y + 2xy^2$$

Example 5: $${d \over dxy}x^2y^2$$
Let $$u = xy, \space x = {u \over y}, \space y = {u \over x}$$
Then $${d \over dxy}x^2y^2 = {d \over du}({u \over y})^2({u \over x})^2 = {4u^3 \over x^2y^2} = {4x^3y^3 \over x^2y^2} = 4xy$$

Is any of this legitimate?

Comment: Taking your first example only: if $y=x^{2}$ and $u=e^{x}$ then the chain rule $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{du}{dx}\frac{dy}{du}$ gives us $2x=e^{x}\frac{dy}{du}$ directly.

Comment: It appears to me that what you are doing is really playing with the chain rule. There is a legitimate way to differentiate with respect to multiple variables or even functions (which can be thought of as infinitely many variables). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative. Knowledge in linear algebra will be required.